# After update weird stuff started happening. Only one display and no nvidia commands worked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, 22.04

I did a normal update using gui since I got a popup. It installed most stuff, but said it couldn't install everything. So I pressed partial installation, thinking I could install the rest after a restart. It didn't look that important the things that where not able to install.

After the restart it only showed on my main display, my side monitors where showing "no input". After a removing nvidia drivers and using the xorg drivers, and a reboot, it worked once again. After this I installed nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary, tested) again and it worked fine. After the first restart no commands, like nvtop or nvidia-smi worked. Had issues communicating with the drivers.

After reinstalling the nvidia drivers it still have issues connecting to the drivers. It do find my card, 1070, when I go to additional drivers and updates. And since I'm using a non IGPU cpu, it shows picture.

So my conclusion is that something went wrong during the update, or one of the now upgradable is very much needed. This is the packages that where not able, and still is unable to install:

```
    zellogi@zellogi-PC:~$ apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.4-0ubuntu1]
language-selector-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.219.1 all [upgradable from: 0.219]
language-selector-gnome/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.219.1 all [upgradable from: 0.219]
systemd-hwe-hwdb/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 249.11.2 all [upgradable from: 249.11.1]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
update-notifier/jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
```

No games or other gpu-workloads seems to work (media, transcoding and VMs).
So question is, how do I continue? What info do you need to help me?

Edit:
Adding command;

```
zellogi@zellogi-PC:~$ nvidia-settings 

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


(nvidia-settings:45719): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:18:56.056: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:45719): CRITICAL **: 14:18:56.057: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have
       been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be
       listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 14:18:56.076: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 14:18:56.076: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I'm not sure how to read this. Something failed.

Comment: Boot back into the previous Kernel, then run `dkms status` and see if the NVIDIA driver carried over into the new kernel update.  There is a possibility that the update might have hiccuped and didn't carry over the driver.  To install the existing driver into the Kernel version that it is missing from it is `sudo dkms -m nvidia -v 525.78.01 -k 5.15.0-58-generic` or whatever Kernel version it is missing from.

Comment: @Terrance 
zellogi@zellogi-PC:~$ dkms status 
nvidia/525.78.01: added
zellogi@zellogi-PC:~$ dkms -m nvidia -v 525.78.01 -k 5.15.0-58-generic
Usage: /usr/sbin/dkms [action] [options]
  [action]  = { add | remove | build | install | uninstall | match | autoinstall | mkdriverdisk |
                mktarball | ldtarball | mkrpm | mkkmp | mkdeb | mkdsc | mkbmdeb | status }
  [options]...
Error! No action was specified.
zellogi@zellogi-PC:~$
I also ran apt install -f and sudo dpkg --configure -a. To be sure nothing was missing, nothing found

Comment: Oops, My bad.  I missed the word install.  `sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 525.78.01 -k 5.15.0-58-generic`

Comment: Alright, now it works in 5.15. The 6.0.? is still having issues. Should I install it again from gui or is terminal safer? Do this remove the 6.. that went wrong?

Comment: Yes, the driver wasn't tested in the 6.0 Kernel yet.  When you run those Mainline Kernels you are running a risk of drivers and applications not working in them yet.  But, you can file bugs with [Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that they can track and fix them.  I would recommend keeping with the Kernel that is defaulted in 22.04 which is still the 5.15 Kernel.  You can try the command as above, but change the `-k` version to match the 6.0 Kernel installed, but there is no guarantee that it will work.

Comment: Fair enough!
Now that you say that I find it a bit weird that it tried to install the 6.0. But maybe I had some setting changed to make it find that. Thanks for all your help! :)